# jQuery fading links except those that are images?

Tags: jquery, image, fading

I have programmed a very simple script with jQuery. The idea is to fade all links with opacity *except* links that are images.

Here is my code:

```
$('#content_wrapper a, #footer_wrapper a, .dcmenu_market_link a').not('a img').each(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.6");
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('fade');
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 600);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 600);
        $(this).removeClass('fade');
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you all non-image containing links -

```
$('a:not(:has(img))')
```

Comment: Excellent! Happy it helped. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped. Thanks :)